# ¿Asociación, composición o agregación?

Tags: uml

Creo que soy capaz de distinguir las diferencias entre los tres tipos de relaciones: **composición**, **agregación** y **asociación**. Sin embargo hay un caso que no se muy bien de que tipo sería. Lo explico con un ejemplo.

Dispongo de la *clase conductor* y la *clase multa*. Una multa puede tener un único conductor y un conductor puede tener muchas multas. La clase multa necesita un conductor para tener sentido, no puede existir una multa sin conductor. Por tanto en el constructor de multa exijo un objeto conductor. la definición de las clases sería así:

```
public class conductor{

    private string dni;
    private string name;

    public conductor(){}
}

public class multa{
    private conductor conductor_multado;

    public multa(conductor conductor_multado){
        this.conductor_multado = conductor_multado;
    }
}
```

¿Cómo podría modelar esta relación? ¿Es una composición con multiplicidad muchas en el lado de multa?

Gracias.

Comment: esta es una pregunta que debería tener una respuesta clara

Answer (score 0):

No es una composición porque la clase `conductor` no tiene (y no le corresponde) el método de agregación de `multa`. Si se podría usar composición para modelar una clase `sistema de multas`.

Se podría modelar por medio de una dependencia, desde `multa` hacia `conductor`. Porque si `conductor` se altera, afecta a `multa`, ya que de primera instancia requiere un conductor para instanciar, valga la redundancia.

Comment: No veo muy claro lo que me comentas... Yo pensaba que las clases que agregan tienen una relación con la agregada de agregación, no de composición, como comentas en la primera parte de la respuesta.

Comment: Además yo pensaba que las clases que agregan tienen una relación con la agregada de agregación, no de composición, como comentas en la primera parte de la respuesta.